# Differentiability of a space consisting of arbitrary circles

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Consider a right circular cone of height h (measured along the z-axis) whose base is a circle on the x-y plane.

Five planes parallel to the x-y plane cut the right circular cone at arbitrary levels (we do not know the z-coordinate of their intersection with the z-axis). Projections of the intersection circles are drawn on a plane (call it D) parallel to but different from the x-y plane.

Is the space consisting of these five projected circles differentiable?

If the number of arbitrary planes is increased to infinity, is the space consisting of projected circles differentiable?

Comment: Functions are what's typically described as differentiable (or not). What does it mean (to you) for a *space* to be differentiable?

Comment: Perhaps I should ask whether the space consisting of the circles is a vector space. But I do not know enough mathematics to know whether that is the right question?